# Button with inverted half circle side in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a stackable bootstrap button with inverted circles on the sides.

Tried with box-shadows and with radial gradients but just couldn't figure it out...

I'd like to also maintain bootstrap's styling - in my case these buttons are navbar-buttons.

The end result should look similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Something like that:

```css
button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 9999em 0 0 9999em;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

button:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>button 1</button>
<button>button 2</button>
<button>button 3</button>
<button>button 4</button>
<button>button 5</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this `CSS`:

```
.buttonCool{
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.shadow{
  margin-left: -12px;
}
```

with this `HTML`:

```
<button class="buttonCool" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<button class="buttonCool shadow" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<button class="buttonCool shadow" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<button class="buttonCool shadow" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5kofmss/1/).

Comment: You can not have same id multiple time in same document!

Comment: @JanNahody Yes, you are right. Sorry for this, I change it right now. Thanks for correct me!